# count an element in a string of a list

Tags: list, count, range

I want to count the letter "`o`" inside each list of this list by using `.count()` function in the empty line

```
F = ["toto", "soso", "lolo"]
k = 0
for i in range(0, len(F)):
  _______________
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate directy over the list (`F`) itself:

```
F = ["toto", "soso", "lolo"]
k = 0
for word in F:
    k += word.count('o')
print(k)
```

`k+=value` is equivalent to `k=k+value`